# Handheld pepper grinder for a wet (and therefore sticky) powder?

Tags: grinding

I am a research scientist trying to find a faster way to feed my animals. Fish food pellets are ground up in a meat grinder. About 99% of the pellets are crushed, and then the animals are handfed the powder by sprinkling it on the water surface. I tried using a pepper grinder, but the moisture in the powder made the powder stick to the grinding mechanism. The 1% of pellets that are uncrushed then clog the mechanism because the grinder becomes too blunt after the powder starts to stick. The new system is slower than handfeeding, but it does work very well until the grinder slows down.

Does anyone know of a handheld grinder that can handle sticky powders? I cannot use an instrument that exceeds the height of a typical household pepper grinder.

Comment: What's wrong with the meat grinder method?

Comment: coffee grinder?

Comment: How big are the pellets, and what consistency are you aiming for in the final product?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a small mortar & pestle, such as a [suribachi](https://www.eater.com/23070540/japanese-suribachi-surikogi-mortar-pestle).  Any rotary grinder is going to have issues with gumming up.  But a suribachi is small, portable, unpowered, and you can use a scraper to clean it quickly if it gets gummed up.

Comment: That's right - I have a grinder sold containing  a spice blend including dried chilli flakes, and even they're too wet - to solution is to tip it into a mortar.